# AngularJS - jQuery - ui-sortable g.sortable is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs, jquery-ui-sortable

I am creating a table with dragable rows with the help of ui-sortable

```
<tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="model.list">
   <tr ng-repeat="item in model.list">
      <td>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control test-input" ng-model="item.Country" ng-readonly="!isEditable">
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control test-input" ng-model="item.Value" ng-readonly="!isEditable">
          </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

This is the code in controller.

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
            update: function(e, ui) {

                console.log(model.list);
            },
            stop: function(e, ui) {

                console.log(model.list);
            }
        };
```

I have made use of require.js and the dependency `ui.sortable` is added over there.

Whenever I open the page with this table, I am getting this error -

`angular.js:12520 
TypeError: g.sortable is not a function
    at w (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.min.js:8:4649)
    at x (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.min.js:8:4721)
    at link (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.min.js:8:5003)
    at http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8835:44
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8841:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8335:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7731:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8330:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7731:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:90/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7734:13) <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="model.list" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope">`

Can you please help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ui-sortable depends on jQuery, jQuery UI 1.9+. Check if you have these dependencies before ui-sortable js file, then you should inject the ui.sortable in the correct module `angular.module('myapp', ['ui.sortable']);`

Comment: The version of jQuery I am using is 2.1 and the injection of `ui.sortable` is also correct.

Comment: Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Did you add the jQuery UI ?

Comment: Require config was creating the problem...
the injections were correct.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who is facing same issue but seems to have everything correct like;

```
1. jQuery is loaded.
2. angular-ui-sortable is being loaded correctly.
3. You've injected its dependency. 
   angular.module('myapp', ['ui.sortable']);
4. The code appears to be correct in the view
```

Make sure you have included `jquery-ui` after `jquery` and before `sortable` js files. I was running with same issue and after a full time headache found this solution [here in this thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/425).

Answer (score 0):

###### Requirements in UI.Sortable directive

AngularJS v1.2+

> JQuery v3.1+
> JQueryUI v1.12+

> If use jQuery v1.x & v2.x then add [UI.Sortable v0.14.x](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) versions